# taking screenshot programmaticallyin ios7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

This the code I use

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen] ;
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *view = [screen snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[keyWindow drawViewHierarchyInRect:keyWindow.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Then I send the data to `SLComposeViewController`

```
 [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

Everything is fine but the image is rotated, my app is only in landscape mode but the screenshot is vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you snapshot UIWindow, who don't handle rotation like UIView / UIViewController. You have to handle rotation yourself.

Try with this code:

```
- (UIImage *)makeSnapshot
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        imageSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    } else {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, window.center.x, window.center.y);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, window.transform);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x, -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.width);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.height, 0);
        } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.width, -imageSize.height);
        }
        if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
            [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        } else {
            [window.layer renderInContext:context];
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```